# Did the invention of the printing press change Judaism?

Tags: tanach

Before 1440 and the invention of the printing press, most Jewish people would not have had their own personal Tanakh. So I would assume the only place they would see one would be in a synagogue read by a Rabbi or other scholarly people.

Do you think this changed Judaism a lot from pre-15th century Judaism?

Having your own Tanach which you could refer to and read every day and debate people with must have been a lot different to the times when people had to go and consult the few copies.

I'm sure there were some richer people who could afford to have their own personal copies copied out by scribes.

Comment: the premise of your question may be false. can you please verify it for clarity?

Comment: Which premise? Books were very expensive in the time before the printing press so not everyone could afford them.

Comment: I don't think Judaism itself changed. Perhaps you could say that the dynamics of the Jewish people changed, with more people becoming more versed in the Tanach, but not the religion itself.

Comment: I think this question needs more focus to be answerable. What do you mean by "changed Judaism a lot"?

Comment: @Harel13 Changed the customs, beliefs, habbits and traditions of the everyday folk. Obviously the text in the holy books stayed the same. But you no-longer have to go to a sinagogue or ask a Rabbi to read the Torah for example. So it could become a more personal religion than relying on authority figures. Assuming that everyday folk could read hebrew which not everyone could or can do today. But there may be local language versions.

Comment: The invention of the printing press changed everything

Comment: @zooby maybe slightly more personalization (in how you define it), but there still are the communal commandments (namely, the need of a synagogue and 10 people to pray, the need for a rabbi to explain the Halacha to you (books aren't enough), etc).

Comment: Prior to the printing press, most cities wouldn't have had even a single full copy of the Babylonian Talmud. Nowadays, your local shul probably has at least a couple, probably including at least one set translated into the local vernacular. Think about the magnitude of change in accessibility to Jewish learning.

Comment: Yes very accessible. Just no one willing to read

Comment: I remember a story a Rav once told me: "My grandfather had to make appointments to go to his teacher's house to consult the Talmud.  Today, I have ten sets of Talmud in my home, and I am not one quarter the scholar my grandfather was."  So, yes, the printing press changed Judaism.  Memory is no longer at a premium.

Comment: BM 85B כי הוו מינצו ר' חנינא ור' חייא אמר ליה ר' חנינא לר' חייא בהדי דידי קא מינצית ח"ו אי משתכחא תורה מישראל מהדרנא לה מפילפולי אמר ליה ר' חייא לר' חנינא בהדי דידי קא מינצית דעבדי לתורה דלא תשתכח מישראל מאי עבידנא אזלינא ושדינא כיתנא וגדילנא נישבי וציידנא טבי ומאכילנא בשרייהו ליתמי ואריכנא מגילתא וכתבנא חמשה חומשי וסליקנא למתא ומקרינא חמשה ינוקי בחמשה חומשי ומתנינא שיתא ינוקי שיתא סדרי ואמרנא להו עד דהדרנא ואתינא אקרו אהדדי ואתנו אהדדי ועבדי לה לתורה דלא תשתכח מישראל היינו דאמר רבי כמה גדולים מעשי חייא

Comment: Whenever R`Hanina and R`Hiyya were in a dispute, R`Hanina said to R`Hiyya: 'Would you dispute with me?

If, Heaven forfend! the Torah were forgotten in Israel, I would restore it by my argumentative powers.'

To which R`Hiyya rejoined: 'Would you dispute with me, who achieved that the Torah should not be forgotten in Israel?

What did I do?

I went and sowed flax, made nets [from the flax cords], trapped deers, whose flesh I gave to orphans, and prepared scrolls [from their skins], upon which I wrote the five books [of Moses].

Comment: Then I went to a town [which contained no teachers] and taught the five books to five children, and the six orders [of the Talmud] to six children(9) And I bade them: "Until I return, teach each other the Pentateuch and the Mishnah;" and thus I preserved the Torah from being forgotten in Israel.'(10) This is what Rabbi [meant when he] said, 'How great are the works of Hiyya!'

Comment: Any change would be marginal, since almost everyone knew how to read before that. The laws of teaching Torah require that every boy be taught how to read Tanach, or at least Chumash. Books on Halacha were widely available. (There are over one hundred manuscripts of the smak, for example.) It wasn't like by the Christians before printing.